# Python - no module named cv2

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pixel, importerror

I found this really funny repo that pixelates images (by simple clustering so there are no weird changing colors) and I found a neat feature for it. It's called [pypxl](https://git.lattuga.net/goat/pypxl)

Now, I run into trouble almost instantly. I am on a windows machine and I mainly use anaconda/conda. First, I used my base environment but when I go:

```
C:/Users/PC/pypxl/pypxl_image.py -k 6 -s 4 4 "C:/Users/PC/pypxl/test.png"
```

I instantly run into trouble with cv2. It tells me that there is no module named cv2. Weird. So I create a new environment (3.8) and I only install the things that pypxl needs (numpy, sklearn and opencv). Same error, no cv2.

Then I try, just out of desperation, to create a py2.7 env (and if you ask me why, I have no good answers) but same error; no cv2. When I activate the environment and check via Spyder, I can import cv2 just fine. I have used cv2 a lot and I can still use it, but when I run that line, I cant. What gives?

Comment: how do you think windows is going to choose the python version that is run with `C:/Users/PC/pypxl/pypxl_image.py`. Try `import sys; print(sys.executable)`

Comment: Since I use anaconda prompt I just activate the environment through there

Comment: so why don't you try pasting my code to the beginning of your file

Comment: Well... when I run it in Spyder, I get C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe

Comment: in your *file*, the `pypxl_image.py`

Comment: I might just be suuuuuper retarded but when I add your code it still wont run because of cv2 import error.

Comment: I am not a psychiatrist but the point is that if you add it *before the cv2* you'd notice that the environment does not affect the interpreter it is using on the command line.

Comment: Okay, so how do I tell it to use the right interpreter?

Comment: Well, you could try using `python c:/.../pypxl_image.py` and that way it would try to run the python interpreter found in path. There might be other tricks on Windows that I am unaware of...

Comment: Oh. My. God. Just when I read your comment it dawned on me. That was one horribly awkward mistake. Thanks! 
Now I just need to figure out why I get a NoneType error.